# robots.txt обработка несколькитх ссылок как одной

Tags: seo, поисковая-оптимизация

Имеется набор ссылок mysite.ru/, mysite.ru/?p=1, mysite.ru/?p=2 и т.д., параметр p скриптом не учитывается. Нужно объяснить поисковику, что это одна и та же страница с общим индексом цитирования. Как это лучше всего сделать? Если не ошибаюсь, тупой Disallow просто отрежет все ссылки с ?p=, потеряв их индекс цитирования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажите в заголовке страницы каноничный адрес этой страницы. Например, как сделано на этом сайте для этого вопроса:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636460/robots-txt-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9" />
```

Подтверждающие учёт тега справки [яндекса](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.xml?lang=ru), [гугла](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru)